# Yammer Login Popup not working on mobile using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, authentication, sdk, ionic-framework, yammer

I had been trying to implement Login with Yammer using the JS SDK that Yammer have developed.
When I tested my app using the browser, the login popup appears and I can proceed with the login as expected.

However, the problem comes when I deploy the app on my Android device.

After clicking the Login with Yammer button, there is no popup.

Any idea how we can make the Login with Yammer button work on mobile device?

Comment: Have you enabled pop-up in mobile browser ? My apps are get crashed when i try to login ..

Comment: Share your solution , that will help me too..

Comment: Yes, i did tried enabling the popup, but still it doesn't work.